# Input of LSTM seq2seq network - Tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, lstm

Using the Tensorflow seq2seq tutorial code I am creating a character-based chatbot. I don't use word embeddings. I have an array of characters (the alphabet and some punctuation marks) and special symbols like the GO, EOS and UNK symbol.

Because I'm not using word embeddings, I use the standard `tf.nn.seq2seq.basic_rnn_seq2seq()` seq2seq model. However, I am confused about what shape `encoder_inputs` and `decoder_inputs` should have. Should they be an array of integers, corresponding to the index of the characters in the alphabet-array, or should I turn those integers into one-hot vectors first?

How many input nodes does one LSTM cell have? Can you specify that? Because I guess in my case an LSTM cell should have an input neuron for each letter in the alphabet (therefore the one-hot vectors?).
Also, what is the LSTM "size" you have to pass in the constructor  `tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(size)`?

Thank you.

Appendix: these are the bugs I am trying to fix.

When I use the following code, according to the tutorial:

```
for i in xrange(buckets[-1][0]):  # Last bucket is the biggest one.
    self.encoder_inputs.append(tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None], name="encoder{0}".format(i)))
for i in xrange(buckets[-1][1] + 1):
    self.decoder_inputs.append(tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None], name="decoder{0}".format(i)))
    self.target_weights.append(tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=[None], name="weight{0}".format(i)))
```

And run the `self_test()` function, I get the error: 
`ValueError: Linear is expecting 2D arguments: [[None], [None, 32]]`

Then, when I change the shapes in the above code to `shape=[None, 32]` I get this error:
`TypeError: Expected int32, got -0.21650635094610965 of type 'float' instead.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the `size` argument passed to `BasicLSTMCell` represents both the size of the hidden state of the LSTM and the size of the input layer. So if you want a different hidden size than input size, you can first propagate your inputs through an additional projection layer or use the built-in seq2seq word embeddings function.

Answer (score 0):

The number of inputs of an lstm cell is the dimension of whatever tensor you pass as inputs to the `tf.rnn` function when instantiating things.

The `size` argument is the number of hidden units in your lstm (so a bigger number is slower but can lead to more accurate models).

I'd need a bigger stack trace to understand these errors.